# Is it legal to not have a surname in Wisconsin?

Tags: name, wisconsin

Is it legal to not have a surname in Wisconsin? Note that I am not American and have no clue where to start looking for the answer. I met someone who claims she doesn't have a surname (her parents and siblings all have surnames, her story is that her parents made an exception for her and didn't give her a surname).

Comment: Was she trying to sell you a dictionary that failed to include the word "gullible?"  If if there is nothing to make this illegal, it would be terribly impractical to go through life under such circumstances.  The impracticality would manifest itself long before this person would reach adulthood.  So this person's parents would likely get weary of this experiment and reverse such a choice before she would get a chance to realize it.

Comment: @grovkin
 Thee are people who have single names, mostly changed by court order in adulthood. "The artist formerly known as Prince" is one well-known example. I don't yet know about Wisconsin law, but I doubt if it legally requires a surname. Yes it can make some things awkward or inconvenient, and not many do it, but it is usually legal.

Comment: @DavidSiegel the example you cited was created for the purposes of furthering a commercial interest, with a great deal of legal advice.  It is, at the very least, likely that the impracticality (and cost) of such a decision would prevent most people from making it casually.  But making such a claim to an acquaintance, while observing their willingness to entertain the possibility, could serve as a lighthearted check of how gullible they are.

Comment: Anecdotal but Indonesia only recently adopted surnames on a widespread basis and many recent immigrants to the U.S. from Indonesia simply made one up for themselves to make life bureaucratically easier for them.

Comment: @ohwillieke I know of one Indonesian who lived in the US without adopting a surname, however.  I suppose he had some strategy for dealing with this problem.  He was a professor at my university, and he was listed in the course catalogue with his real name in the surname field and "Mr" in the first name field.  I somehow doubt that he used that approach everywhere.

Comment: In fact, my acquaintance originates from Indonesia.

Comment: @d-b Did you not think her birthplace- which is presumably where she was named- was not relevant to the question?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim If her birthplace would have been Franc,e or some other civilized country, I am pretty sure she had had a surname. And if she wouldn't have had a surname and migrated to a country where surnames are required she would have been forced to get a surname.

Comment: @d-b People born in the US, such as the person the OP met, usually acquire their initial name through the process of filing a birth certificate in accordance with state law. The requirements for this name would be determined by the laws of the state where the person was born. Thus the state of birth is relevant to providing an answer.

Comment: @GerardAshton I am the OP. Your comment is too US centric.

Comment: @d-b GerardAshton comment, although US based, is also true for most countries in Europe. That is why, to answer your question propery, knowing where the person was born (and thus which name convensions apply) would be the first step in figuring out if such a name is legaly possible.

Comment: d-b I read in your comment to the answer by @grovkin that the acquaintance was born in the US. I assert that different US states have different laws about birth certificates, and one cannot say if only giving the child one name on the birth certificate was lawful without knowing which state the child was born in and the birth date, so the laws as of the birth date could be researched.

Comment: @MarkJohnson No not really, many European countries require you to adhere to their name standard if migrating there.

Comment: @d-b In Germany that is definitly **not** the case. A Russian/Polish, as resident, retain there patronymic name (often with suffix), where a wifes last name can therefore be different than the husbands. If they become citizens they can (but are not required) to change their last name to a sex neutral form ascis common in German Family names. Please supply a list of  European countries (with source) that require you to adhere to their name standard when migrating there.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Does Germany require a German couple that marries to get the exact same surname?

Comment: @d-b No, combinations of the maiden and spouse family name are now possible (or the other way around or no change at all). Sample: [Annegret Kramp-Karrenbauer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annegret_Kramp-Karrenbauer) Kramp=maiden family-name and Karrenbauer=husbands family-name. Her husband (Helmut Karrenbauer) retained his name without change. The choice is made at the time of marriage. [§ 1355 Family name - German Civil Code BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p4841)

Answer (score 4):

It is technically legal, but enforcement of such legality would face insurmountable difficulties without a compelling commercial interest.

## Legality

A [George Washington Law Review article](https://www.gwlr.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/80-1-Larson.pdf)  states that

> An influential 1979 law review
> article concluded that when parents agree, they “should **have the freedom to give their children any reasonable surname**.” Courts could
> disallow “**a surname chosen for a child by his parents if it were so
> outrageous or obscene that it was clearly not in the *child’s best interests*** to bear the surname.” But terms like “reasonable” and “outrageous” are highly subjective and give little guidance to courts on what
> factors to take into account.
>
> The most relevant bodies of constitutional doctrine are substantive due process jurisprudence under the Fourteenth Amendment and
> free speech jurisprudence under the First Amendment. This Part develops the arguments for a parental naming right under both bodies of
> law, and concludes that strict scrutiny is the relevant standard for analyzing restrictions on that right. It further concludes that current laws
> prohibiting certain surnames and laws prohibiting diacritical marks
> are unconstitutional, as they are not narrowly tailored to serve a compelling state interest. Laws against obscenities, ideograms and
> pictograms, and certain length restrictions pass strict scrutiny, as do
> requirements that the child receive at least two names.

Meaning that in the absence of a state law prohibiting a certain naming convention, anything goes.  But states have the power to pass laws to narrowly define what kinds of names are contrary to "compelling state interest."

A [review of relevant history and laws](https://scholarship.law.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1374&context=mulr), applicable to change of surname in a divorce in Wisconsin, concluded that, because of *Jocius v Jocius*, "child's best interest" is not a standard available to Wisconsin courts to empower the courts to force a change of a child's name contrary to parents' wishes.  **Such legislation can be passed, but it hasn't been.**

## Impracticality

However, some of costs associated with having a blank last name would be:

- obtaining insurance
- having any medical procedures
- registering for school
- getting a library card

and many, many more.  In fact, the last two are currently technically impossible because Wisconsin Department of Public Instruction [demands](https://dpi.wi.gov/wise/data-elements/student-name) that "first and last name are required."

It is likely that overcoming the confusion resulting from not having a last name would turn most daily life activities into something that would require a letter from an attorney, or even a court order.  Without a substantial commercial gain from this arrangement, this would be an experiment with an unjustified prohibitive cost.

## Lighter side

The day-to-day difficulties resulting from the absurdities of such an experiment could be easily developed into a plot for a comedy.  Personally, I was imagining a few potential South Park plot lines while trying to think through the implications of this arrangement.

The likely outcome, of not having a real last name, would be that many clerks would end up simply making them up for such an individual, in order to accommodate their computer systems.  And hilarity would undoubtedly ensue.

**Edit**  while I appreciate the "+1"-for-the-effort gesture of the upvotes, I am actually surprised that this answer has gotten as many upvotes as it has.  I would gladly delete it if a better referenced answer, with more specific information, came along.  I wrote this mostly to list the references which I found.  The conclusion which I draw here is what I personally have been able to deduce from those references.  So, please, stop upvoting.  This is not a high-quality answer.  And the fact that the answer is looking like it may very well be "yes" makes this an interesting question, that deserves a better answer.

Comment: Why does the Department of Public Instruction have power over the local library system? I'm not seeing that in the link you provided.

Comment: @doneal24 if you click on "About Us" on the bottom, the 1st line is "The Department of Public Instruction is the state agency that advances public education and libraries in Wisconsin."

Comment: But which category does a general adult fall into on the link? Student or Staff? Do you have to be one or the other to get a library card?

Comment: @doneal24 I don't live in WI and I did have the same reservation about that wording.  But since they don't claim to only administer school libraries, I have to conclude they provide some sort of support for all public libraries in the state.  I can only venture a guess as to what type of ID a non-student would be issued at a public library.  And, of course, my guess would be that they would not be staff.

Comment: The legal situation in Wisconsin could be different for someone born and named elsewhere.  The question doesn't make clear which applies. I know that there are people who live in the US with only one name, so there must be a way of dealing with the impracticalities you mention.

Comment: @phoog My acquaintance is born in the US but has Indonesian parents.

Comment: @d-b This is information that you should add to your question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it shouldn't be necessary to add to the question unless one has to justify having one name, which seems not to be the case.  On the other hand, adding that information to the question might reduce the number of people thinking that the person in question is disingenuously seeking attention.

Comment: If I have one name only, wouldn't that be both my first name and my last name?

Comment: @gnasher729 as far as what? as far as the state law?  as far as what you call yourself?  as far the federal law?  these are all different questions and they may or not have have different answers.  and i am not sure why they are relevant here.  just think about what happens when you try to claim inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

### in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) this is impossible (for german citizens)

- The child **automatically** gains the married surname of the married parents, or one of the two surnames for non-married people, or whatever is the surname of a single parent due to adoption, unknown or death ([§ 1616 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1616.html), [§ 1617](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1617.html) and [$ 1617a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1617a.html)). After $ 1617 (2), if the unmarried parents do not take it into their own hands to choose one of their surnames as the child's surname, the Family court has to assign one of those two to decide, and if no decision is made within a reasonable time, that parent's surname is chosen automatically. There's a possibility for single parents to get the surname of the missing partner under some conditions in $ 1617a.
- There is no provision to remove your surname.
- In fact, under german law, the name attached to you **is not your to tinker with** and you need special reasons to be allowed to change any part of your name. As such an example, you are allowed to request a change of your surname in case that would be *Hitler*, as that surname is very negatively connotated. In fact, the surnames Hitler and Goebbels are nearly extinct in Germany.

  - Note that the "Standesamt" (registry office) can also deny the parents to use first names that are in the view of the office not suitable. And there are judgments that ban (among others) the following first names on various grounds: Dracula, Judas, Lord, Lucifer, Majesty, Pain, Sputnik, Whiskey and **any** town or suburb name, company name or brand. While the combination of "Anakin Skywalker" is barred by judgment, Anakin on its own, as well as Merlin, are ok.
- To have no surname, you can't be born in Germany: In other cultures, people are born without a surname recognized under german law (e.g. an Egyptian Mahmood Ismail Issa has his own first name and then the first names of father and grandfather Mahmood Ismail Issa and no surname). Those people have to choose what shall become their surname if they want to gain German citizenship or other papers. The same happens for Indonesians without surname: The moment they apply for german papers, they can (and have to) choose from any recognized surname.
- If those people are merely born in Germany, they are not forced to adopt a surname - or rather, a *first* name, as the registry will put the full name into the surname category and empty space into the first name because of technical reasons.

Comment: An artist/actor can also have an official **Künstlername** (stage name), which can be used in parallel to their official name. Contracts, signatures can be made for the one or other. Both are contained in their passport and ID.

Comment: @MarkJohnson though Künstrlername is also *special reason*

Comment: A Künstlername does not necessarily change the original name. Lotte Lenya (stage name since 1921) was still Karoline Wilhelmine Blamauer until her first marriage.

Comment: The same is true for religious names. Field 14 of passport: *Benedikt XVI* and  *Ratzinger* in Field 1, *Joseph Aloisius* in Field 2

Answer (score 0):

In a paper in *Columbia Human Rights Law Review* titled ["There is no such thing as a 'legal name'"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3840603) Austin Baker and J. Remy Green offer five ready-to-cite proposals about the existence, or lack thereof, of a "legal name". They conclude in part (p. 162)

1. There is no clear, uniform definition of a legal name.
2. The name a person uses in their community, generally speaking and in the absence of a specific statute providing otherwise (which most states do not have), is their legal name.

They explain there is no coherent "Law of the Name" just as, for example, there is no coherent "Law of the Horse". Horse-related matters are dealt with in diverse areas of the law, such as contracts to buy and sell them, laws about who is responsible if a rider falls off a horse and is injured, etc. Likewise name-related matters are governed by diverse areas of the law. Baker and Green contend that many people falsely believe there is a cohesive "Law of the Name" but in fact different areas of the law, such as common law, the Uniform Commercial Code Article 9, and US immigration law have separate, and sometimes contradictory, provisions about names.

I would draw from this that even if one can find a provision of law in Wisconsin, or federal law that is applicable to people in Wisconsin, that says a single name is sufficient, one can almost certainly find a provision that it is not sufficient.